# How to set up LoRa/LoRaWAN end devices in Google Cloud IoT Core?

Tags: lora, google-cloud-iot, lorawan

I am trying to set up LoRaWAN  end devices on Google Cloud IoT Core under registry and devices bound to the gateway.

LoRaWAN specifies security keys: NwkSKey, AppSKey and AppKey. All keys have a length of 128 bits. However Google Cloud IoT Core requires the following keys.

```
Create a device in registry XXXXXXXX.
Public key format
RS256 
ES256 
RS256_X509 
ES256_X509
```

Has anyone used LoRaWAN end devices directly with Google Cloud IoT Core? How can we set up LoRaWAN end devices bound to a gateway supporting LoRAWAN? We are using LorixOne as a gateway.

Your support much appreciated.

Regards
Jayesh

Currently I am using Lora-App-Server on the VM to handle the end devices, however that does not fit into my overall solution as IoT product.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to the LorixOne, but from [gateway authentication methods](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/gateways/authentication), the "Association Only" auth method might be useful here. That is, the LorixOne can store either the RS256 or ES256 private key and authenticate to Cloud IoT Core via JWTs, while you authenticate devices to the gateway with your existing LoRaWAN security keys.

Assuming you are using the MQTT bridge to connect to Cloud IoT Core, once a device is authenticated through the gateway, the gateway can publish [a message to the `attach` topic for the authenticated device](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/0f94f659e71f6f2d3f0597f512224e23b4f29be9/iot/api-client/mqtt_example/cloudiot_mqtt_example.py#L182) to enable communication.

This link from the LoRaServer official docs might be useful too: [Google Cloud Platform Cloud IoT Core](https://www.loraserver.io/lora-gateway-bridge/integrate/gcp-cloud-iot-core/)